# HTML: Selecting an element from a listbox and link it with a page

Tags: html, listbox

I'm not a lot into HTML and I need some help.

I've a little listbox with 3 elements:

```
<select size="20">
<option>Spiderman</option>
<option>Superman</option>
<option>Hulk</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search!" />
```

What I want is if someone selects "Spiderman" and clicks on Search, I want him to go to the website "Spiderman.html". And the same with the rest ones, if he clicks on Superman, goes to Superman.html, and if he clicks on Hulk goes to Hulk.html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :)

```
<select size="20" id="myselect" >
<option value="spiderman.html">Spiderman</option>
<option value="superman.html">Superman</option>
<option value="hulk.html">Hulk</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search!" onclick="document.location.href = 'http://your-website/' + document.getElementById('myselect').value;" />
```